# Visual Studio Data Compare Msg 3727

Tags: sql

I tried to do data compare with Visual Studio 2012 but got 1 critical error. I was able to to do the comparison between these 2 db before I was forced to update the data compare since I am comparing with another db using SQL 2014. My latest SQL Server Data Tools ver is 11.1.40403.0

Please see below for the screen shot. Has anybody encounter this before and has solution? I am stuck as data compare doesn't has any option to select to bypass constraint check or whatsoever.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved automatically after restart PC.